# What is the difference between IPython and IPython3?

Tags: 13.04, python

They are both on the repos. But I can't find out what the difference is.

Comment: Actually Python 3 was already installed (13.04). Now I am wondering, if I use python 3 stuff, will I be able to use a module that is written for python 2, at the same time? e.g. ScientificPython is not available for 3 on repos

Comment: You will have to check that for each package you need to use. The fact that some package isn't available in the repos does not mean that it is not available to python3. But answering your question: no. If you install a python2 package it is only available to python2. You may be able to get it in python3 using `pip`, for example.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same application, but for different python versions. `IPython` uses Python 2.7 while `IPython3` uses Python 3. If you don't know which one you need probably the right is the 2.7 one, as Python 2.7 comes preinstalled in Ubuntu, while Python 3 has to be installed by you.

There are a lot of packages that follow this naming convention. So if you find a package named `python-XYZ`, probably it is for Python 2.7, and depending on the specific package, there may be also available a `python3-XYZ` package.

Answer (score 1):

ipython uses the python2 libraries and interpreter, while ipython3 uses the python3 libraries and interpreter.

In general it's better to use the non-numbered package, since later it will be upgraded to use python3 automatically when ubuntu switches which version is the default python interpreter.  If you specifically need something from Python 3 now, then install the ipython3 package.

You can check the dependencies and contents of the packages online:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ipython

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ipython3